# Do not deserialize ActiveRecord YAML.load-ing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, deserialization, yaml

Given the YAML content similar to:

```
---
:template: :project_change
:property: !ruby/ActiveRecord:Property
  attributes:
    id: '99'
    name: lorem ipsum 1 dolorem - 101
    status: available
```

**How do I make sure that there will be no queries to the DB when deserialising the content?**

Any `ActiveRecord` values can be ignored, instead of being returned.

The (ugly) workaround I found is this:

`YAML.load(yaml_content.gsub(/(!.+ActiveRecord.+)/, ''))`

Which will convert the YAML above to:

```
---
:template: :project_change
:property: 
  attributes:
    id: '99'
    name: lorem ipsum 1 dolorem - 101
    status: available
```

meaning the ActiveRecord entry becomes a regular hash.

This is really ugly and it would be good if I could tell specifically that I don't want `ActiveRecord` classes to be returned.

Using Ruby 1.9/2, Rails 3.2, fairly recent versions of other gems.

Comment: I'm having a same issue here - I wanted to know if I could track deleted objects. Since object is not persisted in the database anymore, it throws an "Deserialization Error" on YAML.load(serialized). 
And I wanted just to retrieve a mock-object. Any better solution ?